# Javascript select elements by class, change their max-height and then change clicked element max-height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So on each element with class click-to-open when clicked i want all other elements with ths class to set their max-height to 40px and set the clicked div max-height to 500px so I'm trying to do somethin like acordeon.So with Jquery this works but how to implement it in Vanilla JS.

```
 <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.click-to-open').on('click', function(){
                    if($(this).css('max-height') == '40px'){    
                        $('.click-to-open').css('max-height', '40px');
                        $(this).css('max-height', '500px');
                    }
                    else{
                        $('.click-to-open').css('max-height', '40px');
                    }
                });             
            });
        </script>
```

This js script works but else statement seem to not work
Javascript script:

```
(function(){
                var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.click-to-open');
                for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
                    elements[i].addEventListener('click',setMaxHeight);
                }

                function setMaxHeight(){
                    for(var i = 0;i < elements.length; i++){
                        elements[i].style.maxHeight = '40px';
                    }
                    if(this.style.maxHeight == '40px'){                     
                        this.style.maxHeight = '500px';
                    }
                    else {
                        this.style.maxHeight = '40px';
                    }
                }

            })();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function(){
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.click-to-open');
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
        //Add eventlistener to all elements and check height on click
        elements[i].addEventListener('click',checkMaxHeight);
    }

    function checkMaxHeight(){
        //Set maxheight on all elements to 40px
        for(var i = 0;i < elements.length; i++){
            setMaxHeight(elements[i],40);
        }
        //Check if clicked element has maxheight 40px
        if(this.style.maxHeight == '40px'){
            //Set max height on clicked element to 500px
            setMaxHeight(this,500)
        }
    }

    function setMaxHeight(element,value){
        element.style.maxHeight = value + 'px';
    }
})();
```

Comment: i edited with an if statement to imlement the close and do i need to wrap that whole function inside something or just copy paste inside script tag

Comment: You don't need to wrap it inside this self invoking function. Should work inside a script tag aswell

Comment: please rewrite your code with if else statement included

Comment: i added the if statement now